# Replacing TFSBuild.proj files with TFS 2013

Tags: c#

I'm trying to upgrade our TFS server to 2013. We're currently using 2012, but we've also been clinging on to the upgrade template for dear life. With 2013, we'd like to go to the default template and modify it as little as possible.

The problem comes in when you consider that the default template asks you to add each individual .csproj or .sln file that you would like to build. The nice thing about the tfsbuild.proj files is that not only can you build on the server, but you can check out the entire branch and build everything locally, on the command line, by just passing the tfsbuild.proj file to msbuild.exe. Also, developers can own the tfsbuild.proj file without having write access to change the build definition.

What is the replacement for the TFSBuild.proj file in TFS 2013?

My requirements are:
Clean build configuration.
Can easily build everything locally.

What is the solution to this problem in TFS 2013?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a wrapper MSBuild .proj that your TFS build definition uses. We use this technique for NuGet package restore, but it can equally be used to chain together multiple solution files.

For local builds you can use msbuild with that .proj wrapper as the target (I just build the .sln file directly as there is only 1).

.proj file (not suggesting that you should use this exact .proj file, just an example)

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <OutDir Condition=" '$(OutDir)'=='' ">$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)bin\</OutDir>
  <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)'=='' ">Release</Configuration>
  <SourceHome Condition=" '$(SourceHome)'=='' ">$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)</SourceHome>
  <ToolsHome Condition=" '$(ToolsHome)'=='' ">$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)tools\</ToolsHome>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <Solution Include="$(SourceHome)*.sln">
    <AdditionalProperties>OutDir=$(OutDir);Configuration=$(Configuration)</AdditionalProperties>
  </Solution>
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="RestorePackages">
  <Exec Command="&quot;$(ToolsHome)NuGet\NuGet.exe&quot; restore &quot;%(Solution.Identity)&quot;" />
</Target>

<Target Name="Clean">
  <MSBuild Targets="Clean"
           Projects="@(Solution)" />
</Target>

<Target Name="Build" DependsOnTargets="RestorePackages">
  <MSBuild Targets="Build"
           Projects="@(Solution)" />
</Target>

<Target Name="Rebuild" DependsOnTargets="RestorePackages">
  <MSBuild Targets="Rebuild"
           Projects="@(Solution)" />
</Target>
```

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't sure if that was the only way, or the "right" way according to MS, or what. Unfortunately, while MS has improved TFS documentation, it seems as though the TFSBuild.proj documentation is not up to par on MSDN.